# How to set up SSH 2FA with either publickey+token or password+token?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, password, pam

I have tried to set up PAM authentication for SSH to a Ubuntu 18.04 server (by modifying the instructions in [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04)). I am attempting to set the login so that any of these two combinations is enough to log into the server:

1) publickey + token
2) password + token

However, no matter which settings I try to use, it does not work. I am editing the following two files:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

As far as I understand, I need the following two lines in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods password,keyboard-interactive publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

and then comment out the following line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
#@include common-auth
```

but if I set it up like this, it leads to an interesting state:

1) If I try to log in with publickey+token, everything works:

```
Authenticated with partial success.
Verification code:
```

I type in my 2FA token and I am in.

2) However, if I try password+token, I first get prompted for a password

```
user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx's password:
```

but a correct SSH password **does not** work. What works for this prompt is the 2FA token (why? it explicitely asked for a password). After passing this prompt, I get prompted for

```
Verification code:
```

which also asks for the token. So I can successfully log into the server by typing in the same token TWICE IN A ROW.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get what I want? Are there any logs I should provide? Am I trying to do something unreasonable?

Thanks!